# c# cannot read a (not very large) text file (IndexOutOfRange)

Tags: c#, file, text, indexoutofboundsexception

My purpose is to read a text file (<50 mb) and perform a regex on it and then save it back to another file (in c#). How i am doing that is posted below.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(regex.Split(line,2)[1]);
            File.WriteAllText(regex.Split(line,2)[1]);                    
        }
```

When i try this with a small file (140KB) it works fine.
When i run the same with a file of size ~ 50 MB, it crashes
Does it have anything to with performing a regex inside the loop?

IndexOutOfRange is the exception that is thrown. What i cannot understand is how a 45mb file can run my system out of memory? I have 8 gigs of RAM installed.

Comment: The split() does not return an array with an element at index 1

Comment: Read the exception. Inspect the stack trace. Isolate the code. For example you could introduce a variable `string[] split = regex.Split(line,2)`, then test that that array actually has two elements.

Comment: Not that this is your problem...but when you're running through VS, it's going to only reserve so much memory for the program. [An article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2010/09/27/10068359.aspx) on this.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with available memory.  The `IndexOutOfRange` exception is only thrown when the code tries to access an item in the array at an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Tony Vitabile I didnt know that, thank you
@Alex k. Its not the split that is returning the element, its the regex.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a line where `regex.Split(line,2)[1]` is null. Add a check

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
 var lines = File.ReadLines(path);

 foreach (var line in lines)
 {
     var item = regex.Split(line,2);
     if(item.Length > 1)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(regex.Split(line,2)[1]);
          File.WriteAllText(regex.Split(line,2)[1]);   
     }                 
 }
```

and it should work

Comment: No, split won't yield `null` entries and a `null` won't throw the mentioned exception. This code will work with the test `> 1`.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure so added it for completeness sake. Answer updated

Comment: Tested it, no output. Blank!

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfRange` is thrown when you try to access an array index that doesn't exist. Your code has an array access on the array returned by the Split() calls. Thus, it is likely that you are failing when Split() returns an array with fewer than 2 elements such that index 1 is not valid. Note that the second argument to Split is only the MAXIMUM number of splits: there is no minimum. You may want to perform additional validation on your input or do something like .Last() instead of [1].

Comment: Adding .last instead of [1] actually worked, but the string appears as is, instead of being split into two.

Comment: @Sid: at the point where this happens, what is the value of line?

Answer (score 0):

After you fix your first issue with referencing the incorrect index, you will have an issue with you constantly calling File.WriteAllText in a loop.  This solves both issues and doesn't keep opening/closing the destination file.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");
File.WriteAllLines(path2,File.ReadLines(path).Select(line=>{
  var items=regex.Split(line,2);
  return items.Length>1?item[1]:"";
}));
```

Comment: What might p be? I'm not sure what would be the file object here?

Comment: @Sid Sorry, p was supposed to be line, fixed.